# Vuejs 2 terminal directives or higher priority directives?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to create an [autovivification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autovivification) directive for my Vue app.

So basically if my `data` has a `user` object, e.g. `{user:{}}` and I create the following input:

```
<input type="text" v-model="user.info.name.first" v-autovivify>
```

My directive will automatically create the desired path inside the user object, e.g. `user.info.name.first` (similar to how it worked in Angular 1.0)

My problem is that before my `v-autovivify` directive is called, `v-model` already evaluates and throws an error:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"
```

But I do know this can be done, because here is a trick I'm using to *autovivify* objects right now:

The `vivify` methods just creates the nested object and returns true

```
methods: {
   vivifyUser() {
        //this should of course check if the path exist but removed for brevity.
        this.user = {name: {first: {salut: ''}}};
        return true;
   }
   // other methods, etc...
```

What this means is `v-if` is called before `v-model` is evaluated and so I'm able to create the path and no error is thrown.

**So my question is how can I set the priority of my directive higher than `v-model`** (just like v-if has a priority)?

Answer (score 2):

Add a `v-if` to delay the rendering of the element.

```html
<input v-if='user.info' type="text" v-model="user.info.name.first" v-autovivify>
```

or even more general

```html
<input v-if='user && user.info' type="text" v-model="user.info.name.first" v-autovivify>
```

This is a common pattern used when working with async-computed properties.

Comment: that's useful but i don't want to add v-if. What i'm looking for is a way to write my own `v-if` kind of directive that takes precedence over other things like v-model, etc. There was something called `terminal` in Vue 1.0 but I can't find it's equivalent in v2.

Comment: I'm also interested in knowing about this. v-if does not seem like an elegant solution at all.